# How to get value of content attribute from span class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My diction is going to be wrong, so forgive the misnomers. I'm looking for the text of the "content" within the span class:

```
<span class="rating-label" content="5">
```

I'm looking for "5"

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('rating-label').text
```

But I do not receive the "5" back anywhere in that text.

I've also tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rating-label').get_attribute("outerHTML")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rating-label').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

I've checked the other questions about this, but if I missed one feel free to show me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *content* attribute is having the value **5**. So to extract the value you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.rating-label"))).get_attribute("content"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='rating-label']"))).get_attribute("content"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```